# Bash script fails to exit when pipelined to tee

Tags: bash, pipeline, tee

I have a script for following a log file to determine if a server has started, and it goes something like this:

```
echo "Starting server."
./start_server.sh

sleeptime=0
while [ ${sleeptime} -lt 60 ]
do
    sleep 5

    serverlog=$(tail -n 5 ./server.log)
    echo ${serverlog} | grep -iq "Server startup"

    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        echo "Server startup successful"
        exit 0
    fi

    let sleeptime=sleeptime+5
done

echo "Warning: server startup status unknown."
exit 1
```

When I run the script (./start_server.sh), the script exits fine. However, when I pipeline it to tee (./start_server.sh | tee -a serverstartup.log), the script doesn't end unless I force it (ctrl + C).

Why doesn't the script exit when pipelined to tee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server script spawned a child process that never terminated because it started up a daemon. tee was waiting for the child process to terminate, resulting in this issue.

More details here: [Why does tee wait for all subshells to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595199/why-does-tee-wait-for-all-subshells-to-finish)

Answer (score -1):

change :

```
while [ ${sleeptime} -lt 60 ]
```

to

```
while [ ${sleeptime} -le 60 ]
```

Comment: What is the difference between < and <= in this case? Wouldn't it just be five more seconds? (trying it out now)

Comment: add set -x  and see where it goes to endless loop  ;  what is the server ops and what bash version

Comment: (sorry don't know how to format this better). This is the last thing I see:

+ grep -iq 'Server startup in'
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'INFO:     Server successfully started.'
INFO:     Server successfully started.
+ echo 'INFO:     Upgrade completed.'
INFO:     Upgrade completed.
+ exit 0

Comment: Bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release