# Why does tee wait for all subshells to finish?

Tags: bash, pipeline, tee, subshell

I have a server script that runs mysqld and forks to continue running. As an example:

```
./mysqld <parameters> &
echo "Parent runs next line in script."
<do more stuff>
```

Why does tee wait for the child process to end before it ends itself?

EDIT:

For example, the following always hangs:

```
./myscript | tee -a logfile.log
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you have `tee`.

Comment: `tee` doesn't wait for any children. It has none.

Comment: @n.m. I think the asker means the child process of the script, i.e. the mysqld process.

Comment: that's what I meant - thanks for clarifying @davmac

Comment: I added an example to clarify - thanks for the headsup @konsolebox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it can't be sure it has tee'd all the output if the child process is still running (and still has its standard output open).

Since the parent and child use the same standard output (which is connected to `tee`'s input, due to the pipe), there is no way for `tee` to distinguish them. Since it consumes all input, both the parent and child must close their standard output (or terminate) before `tee` will see and end-of-input condition.

If you want `tee` to exit when the parent script does, you should redirect output of the child (to a file or to `/dev/null` for example).

Comment: And the pipeline waits until both the parent and child has ended?

Comment: tee waits until its input file descriptor returns no more data (read operation fails or returns EOF). That won't happen until both the parent and child close their stdout (or terminate).

Comment: you can avoid this, by the way, by redirecting the output of the child process.

Comment: sounds great @davmac - we redirected the output of the child process, but I wanted to confirm that we understood the problem when I asked the question. Thanks for your help!