# Tee command: Process output not available till process completes

Tags: linux, console, tee

I have a long running process that outputs status messages, errors and warnings to console. I want to log this output to a file and also see it on the console.

Using `foo_command | tee foolog.txt` does the job but `foolog.txt` remains empty till `foo_command` has completed.

What I want is live output to foolog.txt so that anyone can tail `foolog.txt` to monitor the status. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595199/why-does-tee-wait-for-all-subshells-to-finish

Comment: @fedorqui but it does not answer my question. How do I make tee or any other command write live output to file?

Comment: @Dojo `tee` does write `live` output to a file

Comment: @BroSlow I `tail`ed `foolog.txt` and did not see any output till the process ended.